# HTML big text and have 2 lines of small text next to it?

Tags: html, css

I want the text to look like:

[image: Ideal Page]

My code is

```css
.number {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: inline;
}

.top {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <p class="number" id="num">12</p>
  <p style="display: inline;" id="month">Oct</p>
  <p style="display: inline;" id="year">2021</p>
</div>
```

with default text size being 16px, and the big 12 in the picture is 32px.
I currently have it that it shows [image: Current] How do I make the 2021 text appear on a new line, while having the 12 text be to the left of these 2 lines? Note, removing the inline makes them appear below the 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use flex instead of inline.

This way you can control the spacing between left and right elements more easily using `gap`.

In this example I also adjusted the line-height of the month and year to account for the height of the 12 but this is optional based on what you want the look to be.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem
}

.number {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.right p {
  line-height: .9
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <p class="number" id="num">12</p>
  <div class="right">
    <p id="month">Oct</p>
    <p id="year">2021</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed.